# How can I remove a device that is displayed when installing an application from Google Play's "Choose a device" list?

Tags: google-play-store

I am trying to install an application from Google Play on my Android device, but I see several devices listed in the "Choose a device" screen that I no longer use or own. This range from actual devices to emulators like Virtual android machines and android emulators. In the image below, devices I would like to remove everything except **S21_Plus** such as *Asus ASUS_Z01QD, Verizon SM-G925V, Google SDK_gphone64_x86_64, OnePlus NE2211,* etc...
[image]
Is there any way to remove the devices from the list so that only my active and currently owned devices are displayed?

**EDIT**:

I have come across what seems to be a now [outdated article](https://www.nextpit.com/how-to-remove-my-device-from-google-play) that states you can remove the devices within Google Play. However, when I attempted the same I was only given the option to *hide* and not remove. This was also shown in [these steps from Google](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2407656?hl=en).
[image]

**EDIT2**:

It seems that even attempting to "hide" any devices besides *S21_Plus*, they are automatically re-enabled as shown from the gif below. Is this a **glitch with Google Play**??
[image: auto-reenabled-odd]

Answer (score 3):

You can see and manage all devices registered in your account on your [Google device management](https://myaccount.google.com/device-activity) page.

If you select a device there you can log-off it.

Comment: *You’re signed in on these devices or have been in the last 28 days. There might be multiple activity sessions from the same device*. None of the devices in my screenshot (one is in June) I see in the link that you shared.

Comment: @kyrlon had you used always the one Google account you are currently logged-in on the shown devices?

Comment: yes. Also I have updated my question from some articles I have come across.

Comment: @kyrlon based on my experience with emulators and my older broken devices, AFAIR, you have to log them off (from Google's "Your devices" link in this answer) to remove it from the Play Store.

Comment: @AndrewT. I have emulators/VMs that I have destroyed and none of them appear in my "Your devices"